# Redirecting from PHP page after jQuery $.ajax post

Tags: php, ajax

I'm using $.ajax to submit my data to a PHP page and I know I can do a redirect when success response is returned. However, is there a way to execute a redirect from my PHP page where I post to?

Comment: Please show your code and what you've tried.

Comment: `execute a redirect from my PHP page where I post to` yes but it's largely pointless.  You can't output anything before the redirect, and you naturally lose any state when doing the redirect.  So generally your better going to the page you want to.  At best your loading whatever "code/framework" your using 1 extra time, for no real reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you want. The code below post data to server php backend via **ajax** and redirect users if posted data is not 
empty

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){


        $('#signin').click(function(){


    var username = $('#username').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();

            if(username==""){

                alert('please Enter username');


            }

     else if(password==""){

                alert('please Enter password');


            }

    else{

    $('#loader').fadeIn(400).html('<span>Please Wait, User is being logged</span>');

    var datasend = "username="+ username + "&password=" + password;

            $.ajax({

                type:'POST',
                url:'login.php',
                data:datasend,
                            crossDomain: true,
                cache:false,
                success:function(msg){

                    //empty username and password box after submission
                    $('#username').val('');
                    $('#password').val('');

                    $('#loader').hide();
                    $('#result').fadeIn('slow').prepend(msg);
                    $('#fadeoutResult').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');

                }

            });

            }

        })

    });


    </script>





            <input
                name="username"
                type="text"
                class="form-control input-lg"
                id="username"
            />

            <input
                name="password"
                type="password"
                class="form-control input-lg"
                id="password"
            />


<div id="loader"></div>
<div id="result"></div>


            <button type="submit" id="signin">
                Submit
            </button>
```

**test.php**

```
<?php

// lets do redirect if username and password is not empty. you can apply the same principle is your submission is successful

$username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
$password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);


if ($username != '' && $password !=''){
header('Location: success.php');
exit();
}


?>
```

Answer (score 2):

### PHP

If you want a PHP way you can set the header.

```
header('Location: www.example.com');
```

**Warning** you can only use header if you haven't sent any other information to the client.

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is
>   sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.
>   It is a very common error to read code with include, or require,
>   functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty
>   lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem
>   exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

### Javascript

You can redirect the browser using the following:

```
window.location = "www.example.com";
```

This can be done at any time.

Sources: [PHP-Header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) [JS-Window-Location](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp)